# amazon s3 image not working correctly on Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-s3, meteor-autoform

Hello guys I want to know why are the images not being displayed correctly on my android device. they are displaying properly on web but on mobile and by the way I am developing my application in meteor. there are some places it is displaying correctly but at one place it is not displaying. I am using quickfield for displaying my image. The code for displaying the image is given below:

```
<div class="upload-btn-holder">
  <div class="fileUpload">
    <div class="form-group mdi-content-add upl-img prof-img-circle">
    {{> afQuickField name='profile.picture'}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: afQuickField is part of autoform. What's working differently in the form on web and cordova? It could be an issue of your `mobile-config.js` file not allowing access to your S3 bucket. You need to set the correct access rules as explained here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/App-accessRule (If you're not using Cordova this isn't relevant though)

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock
image is being displayed on the web but not on the mobile device. second of all I have allowed it.  third of all its present on the local I saw the url on the web it was like this

`/cfs/files/data/LvTLQkKzE8QghgGKs/Funny-Guys-Boys-in-Gym-Exercise-Picture17921940_201315056.jpg?token=eyJhdXRoVG9rZW4iOiI5VFZibEl6cmFLUWY3UmRLM01xNmNGc1JyakhLaXRzYk9sUUs3RHEtT1hZIn0%3D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I found the solution.I just needed to update the cfs package.